# ¿Como eliminar un elemento de un array por el contenido del mismo?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Tengo un array en android (java)  y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de eliminar un campo de ese array no por el id (realizando un for) sino por el contenido del mismo... me explico

Mi array lleva "Luis","Juan","Manuel"

como lo haria para eliminar a juan?

Intente esto pero no funciono...

```
listInvitados invitado=new listInvitados();
    //remove from list array
    listInvitadoslist.remove(invitado.getName);
```

Existe alguna manero de hacerlo...

Comment: Hola, podrias mostrarnos la clase listaInvitados para ver de que extiende exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes el ArrayList `listInvitados` conteniendo los elementos:

```
["Luis","Juan","Manuel"]
```

puedes eliminar el elemento por su nombre:

```
 listInvitados.remove("Juan");
```

---

Puedes usar un método donde especifiques la lista original y el nombre del elemento que deseas eliminar.

```
public ArrayList<String> eliminaElemento(ArrayList<String> listOfElements, String name){

        for (Iterator<String> iterator = listOfElements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            String value = iterator.next();
            if (value.equals(name)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return listOfElements;
    }
```

Lo anterior sería llamado de esta forma para eliminar "Juan":

```
 listInvitados =  eliminaElemento(listInvitados, "Juan");
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la base de que no puedes eliminar un elemento de un array mientras lo estas iterando, puedes probar:

Te creas una lista auxiliar en la que vas a guardar los objetos que quieres eliminar.

```
List<Invitado> paraBorrar = new ArrayList<>();
```

Recorres la lista principal y cada vez que encuentres un elemento que quieras eliminar lo añades a la lista auxiliar.

```
for (Invitado invitado : listaInvitados) {
   if (invitado.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
       paraBorrar.add(invitado);
   }
}
```

Finalmente recorres la lista de elementos que quieres borrar y los eliminas del array principal

```
for (Invitado borrar : paraBorrar) {
    listaInvitados.remove(borrar);
}
```

el método completo sería:

```
public void eliminarPersona(List<Invitado> listaInvitados, String nombre) {

    List<Invitado> paraBorrar = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Invitado invitado : listaInvitados) {
        if (invitado.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
            paraBorrar.add(invitado);
        }
    }

    //Eliminas de la lista principal los que hayas añadido en la auxiliar
    for (Invitado borrar : paraBorrar) {
        listaInvitados.remove(borrar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es que uses funciones lambda con Java 8:

```
listInvitados.removeIf(listInvitados -> listInvitados.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("Juan"));
```

tener en cuenta que para usar lambda en Android debes tener instalado Java 8 y tener la compatibilidad en tu gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Y versión minima de android 24 o "N", si quieres usar en versiones posteriores te aconsejo usar Retrolambda

https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda